# How can I write to a file but keep \n as it is rather than adding a new line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program that contains all my other programs however when I attempt to write to the file it prints `\n` as a new line rather than literally `\n`.

For Example:

```
file.write("""a=input("What would you like?\n")
```

Produces:

```
a=input("What would you like?

")
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the backslash `\` to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning such as the
*newline, backslash itself, or the quote character* for example.

Therefore use:

```
file.write("""a=input("What would you like?\\n")""")
```

Or make it a raw string by adding a `r` in front of the string:

```
file.write(r"""a=input("What would you like?\n")""")
```

Comment: In the second example, you have the `r` in the wrong place: it should go at the begining of the triple-quote.

Comment: The two examples do not write the same file. The first one will contain the string `'a=input("What would you like?\\n")'`; the second one will contain the string `'a=input(r"What would you like?\n")'`. Note that I'm assuming that the _real_ example code should be `file.write("""a=input("What would you like?\n")""")`: i.e. it has a missing closing triple-quote and parenthesis. Without that assumption, the code is not valid python.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because you didn't fix the second example properly (see my second comment above). Also, for consistency, you should probably fix the your first example, too.

Comment: @ekhumoro I seem to be a bit confused BTW is the second example now fixed as per you?

Comment: Yes, as it stands, they will now both write the same string. And just to be clear, I'm assuming that the OP wants the contents of the file to be **literally** this: `a=input("What would you like?\n")`.